# Python unit testing - how to mock flask.current_app

Tags: python, unit-testing, mocking

I have the following method in my flask app, part of a healthchecks api:

```
from flask import current_app

class Healthcheck():
    @classmethod
    def check_running(cls):
        if(current_app):
            return True, "OK"
        else:
            return False, "Fail"
```

My question is, how do I unit test the failure condition? These are my tests:

```
def testRunningCheck_pass(self, flask_test_client):
    result = Healthcheck.check_running()
    assert result[0] == True, "Unexpected check result"
    assert result[1] == "OK", "Unexpected check message"

@patch("flask.current_app")
def testRunningCheck_fail(self, flask_test_client):
    result = Healthcheck.check_running()
    assert result[0] == False, "Unexpected check result"
    assert result[1] == "Fail", "Unexpected check message"
```

`testRunningCheck_pass` passes, but `testRunningCheck_fail` bombs out with this error:

```
./tests/test_healthcheck.py::TestHealthcheck::testRunningCheck_fail Failed: [undefined]RuntimeError: Working outside of application context.

This typically means that you attempted to use functionality that needed
to interface with the current application object in some way. To solve
this, set up an application context with app.app_context().  See the
documentation for more information.
args = (<tests.test_healthcheck.TestHealthcheck object at 0x110af3b50>,)
keywargs = {}

    @wraps(func)
    def patched(*args, **keywargs):
>       with self.decoration_helper(patched,
                                    args,
                                    keywargs) as (newargs, newkeywargs)
```

Is there a way to mock `flask.current_app` and control what is presented and be able to test that failure condition?